# symfony Работа с файлами

Tags: symfony2, symfony3

Как в сифони реализована работа с файлами? 
К примеру у меня есть статический файл, и хочу его сделать доступным для скачивания. Как мне нужно генерировать для него путь в шаблонизаторе Twig. 
Я знаю есть asset но как я понял он позиционируется для CSS, JS и image файлов.

Comment: Как вариант, используя переменную `%kernel.root_dir%` [ответ на ваш вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872529/get-kernel-root-dir-in-twig-template-with-symfony-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов решения проблемы.

Если Вы хотите, чтобы Вы могли каким-либо образом обрабатывать скачивание файла (например, считать количество загрузок и записывать их в БД или же предоставлять доступ только определенным пользователям), то Вы можете сделать отдельный контроллер под это дело и выдавать содержимое файла в качестве ответа (тут тоже есть несколько вариантов, но их лучше расписывать в отдельных вопросах).

Если Вы хотите разгрузить сервер и отдавать файлы статикой (например, через nginx, который настроен как прокси), Вы можете использовать тот же `{{ asset() }}` и для генерации ссылок на файлы. Предположим, что нужный нам файл лежит в папке `web/files/example.pdf`. Тут опять есть несколько подходов:

- Вы можете в каждом вызове `asset` прописывать полный путь до файла относительно директории `web/`

  **В шаблоне**:

  ```html
  <a href="{{ asset('/files/example.pdf') }}">Link</a>
  ```
- Вы можете прописать конкретный префикс для определенных файлов в виде "пакета" и использовать `asset` с указанием этого пакета. В таком случае Вы получите легко-изменяемый путь до папки файлов: вдруг, Вы решите пересмотреть структуру каталогов. Пример:

  **В конфиге**:

  ```yaml
  framework:
      templating:
          packages:
              files:
                  base_urls: /files
  ```

  **В шаблоне**:

  ```html
  <a href="{{ asset('/example.pdf', 'files') }}">Link</a>
  ```

Comment: Я решил эту задчу раньше по первому методу. Хотелось бы узнать больше про несколько вариантов которые вы упомянули. Если вас не затрудник давайте свяжемся и вы мне расскажете . Буду очень благодарен.